# How can I filter within a created column in pgsql

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query in pgsql to extract a tabular view that has the 3 columns - node, value and time. The column node is created and if I try to filter for a specific node, I get a message - "node is not a column in the table metrics" so do I need to use regex or a specific `where node like xyz`.

Query:

```
select label->>'machine' as node, value, time 
from metrics 
where metrics.name='total_bytes' and time<'09-22-2020' 
group by node, metrics.value, metrics.time 
order by node;`
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You can write the clause this way:

```
where label->>'machine' like 'xyz'
```

To use `node` directly, you could do this:

```
with my_metrics as (
  select label->>'machine' as node, value, time 
  from metrics 
  where metrics.name='total_bytes' and time<'09-22-2020'
)

select node, value, time
from my_metrics
where node like 'xyz'
group by node, value, time 
order by node;
```

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. Right now I see an empty table but I see how the query ought to work so let me see why it isn't working.